# How to activate and use templates in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Apache IoTDB prompts that the template has already been used in time series, but I checked and  it is actually not used when querying and cannot be activated. Anyone know what may be the reason and how can I successfully use the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template of Apache IoTDB needs to be created first, then mounted (set), then activated. The activation path needs to be the mounting path (and its sub-paths). The query statement after mounting should be like `show paths set schema template xx`. You can check if your path name and query statement are appropriate.